# Jekyll blog on Heroku not updating the non-www subdomain site

Tags: heroku, blogs, jekyll

We have developed and deployed a Jekyll site and portfolio and deployed it to Heroku.

For some strange reason, the site at http://blueverve.com and the site at http://www.blueverve.com are out of sync.

Has anyone come across something like this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your DNS records have been setup incorrectly with your registrar.

For http://blueverve.com/ I see these nameservers:

```
ns-1082.awsdns-07.org.
ns-1961.awsdns-53.co.uk. 
ns-337.awsdns-42.com.
ns-753.awsdns-30.net.
```

For http://www.blueverve.com/ I only see this:

```
ns-927.amazon.com.
```